# Two simple routes not work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

how do I make this route works:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Custom",
            url: "{modality}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I need to call if I want this:

`/ModalityName/SomeController/SomeAction/SomeId`

or

`/SomeController/SomeAction/SomeId`

but the second route that is the default from mvc is not working.

I just need some times to inform the modality so I can get some content based on that

Comment: I think it's because you've set "modality" as optional, haven't set its default value.
So when you call
<code>
/SomeController/SomeAction/SomeId</code>
It defaults to 2nd route i.e. "Default".

Comment: And, if you make it optional and set its default value, the 2nd route will never be evaluated as the first route woul always match the url pattern.
So, the user must enter url pattern upto modality so that it doesn't default to 2nd route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes are evaluated for a match to an incoming URL in order

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Custom",
    url: "ModalityName/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "ModalityName",
        action = "action",
    }
);



routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

}

More Information Read Link :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC